# Assigning nodes to a hierarchical tree/network programatically

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph

I have a network/tree which looks like this.

[image]

I have used a binary tree to represent this model. However manually assigning the `right` and `left` parameters of a node become cumbersome for levels > 4.

Is there a method by which I can do the above assignment programatically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can at first create a 2D array of nodes where row `i` corresponds to level `i` on your paper, and column `j` corresponds to the `j`-th node in that level:

```
for i = 1 to n:
   for j = 1 to i:
      A[i][j] = new Node()
```

Then, the relationship between nodes is, the `A[i][j]` node has left child being `A[i+1][j]` and has right child being `A[i+1][j+1]`.

```
for i = 1 to n-1:
   for j = 1 to i:
      A[i][j].left = A[i+1][j]
      A[i][j].right = A[i+1][j+1]

for j = 1 to n:
   A[n][j].left = null
   A[n][j].right = null
```